# Why doesn't the memory initialize even if I reload from FastAPI?

Tags: html, jinja2, fastapi

There may be an answer to this question, but I'm asking because I don't know which keyword to search for.

I'm using **"FastAPI"** and **"Jinja2"** to show time series data with **"3million rows"** and **"9 columns"** on the web.

At this time, the **"memory occupies"** almost **"2 gigabytes"**, and if it is reloaded in this state, the memory is **"not initialized"** and **"continues to accumulate"**.

Is there a way to initialize the memory when **"reloading"** or **"going back"** pages?

Comment: I can't really think of a business case to concurrently display 3 million rows, shouldn't it be possible to paginate/batch the data and use some client event to load or replace (extra) rows? Either way you'll need to add some details to clarify what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide Technically, it doesn't just show the data. I'm using 3 million data to show outlier data graphs and missing data graphs.

Comment: Without knowing details, I would suggest it's possible, or even common practice to heavily preprocess data before sending it to a frontend application